# Powershell trying to improve my File-Deletion script

Tags: powershell, recursion, directory

**Update**

Thanks to the answer provided by Mathias, I was able to crate this script instead, which is FAR more succinct, and introduces me to the concept of PSBoundParamater

```
Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$Path,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [int]$Days,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [switch]$Recurse
)

# Define the age threshold
$timespan = New-TimeSpan -Days $days -Hours 0 -Minutes 0

# Remove the Days parameter from the input arguments
$PSBoundParameters.Remove('Days')

# Splat the remaining arguments and filter out files newer than $Days 
Get-ChildItem @PSBoundParameters -File|Where-Object {((Get-Date) - $_.LastWriteTime) -gt $timespan} |%{ Remove-Item $_.FullName }
```

---

I have written the following script in Powershell for the purpose of deleting all files from a directory which are more than some no of days old. The user has the option of applying the `-recursive` switch to include all child folders:

```
# CMD input command:
# .\ScriptName.ps1  -path '\\Path\to\files\here' -days x
#
# E.G: 
# .\DeleteFiles.ps1 -path '\\file\IT\SK\scripts' -days 1 -recursive

Param (
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$path,
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[int32]$days,

[parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[switch]$recursive
)

# Set the timespan based on $days entered
$timespan = New-TimeSpan -Days $days -Hours 0 -Minutes 0

######################################################################################
# Delete-Files deletes all the files in the specified directory only
######################################################################################
function Delete-Files {
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$path,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [TimeSpan]$timespan
)

    # | pipes the output and ` allows multiline command
Get-ChildItem $path | `
Foreach-Object{
    $lastmodified = $_.LastWriteTime
    $fullname = $_.FullName

    If (((Get-Date) - $lastmodified) -gt $timespan) {
        Remove-Item $fullname
    }
}
}

######################################################################################
# Delete-All deletes all files frmo the specified directory and all subdirectories
######################################################################################
function Delete-All {
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$path,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [TimeSpan]$timespan
)

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include *.* -File -Recurse | ` 
foreach {
    $lastmodified = $_.LastWriteTime
    #$fullname = $_.FullName

    If (((Get-Date) - $lastmodified) -gt $timespan) {
        $_.Delete()
    }
}
}

######################################################################################
# Main
######################################################################################
If ($recursive) {
    Delete-All -path $path -timespan $timespan 
}

Else {
    Delete-Files -path $path -timespan $timespan
}
```

However, I feel that this isn't the best way of going about this, as each option (recursive or not recursive) uses a different method to delete the items.

I tried removing the `-Recurse` option from the 'Delete-All' method and adding it to `Delete-Files`, but this resulted in no files being deleted at all:

```
function Delete-Files{
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$path,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [TimeSpan]$timespan
)

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include *.* -File | ` 
foreach {
    $lastmodified = $_.LastWriteTime
    #$fullname = $_.FullName

    If (((Get-Date) - $lastmodified) -gt $timespan) {
        $_.Delete()
    }
}
}
```

Is this a required field? If so, could anyone please suggest a way which I can reduce this code to only contain 1 method, or 2 methods which call the same procedure?

** Example input at the top of the code**

Comment: If this is otherwise working, please ask your question on codereview (codereview.stackexchange.com) instead

Comment: Thanks Mathias - Is there a way to move the question over, or should I just delete/leave this as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cook the entire script body down to just 3 lines (2 if you move `Get-Date` into the `Where-Object` filter):

```
Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$Path,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [int]$Days,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [switch]$Recurse
)

# Define the age threshold
$Threshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)

# Remove the Days parameter from the input arguments
$PSBoundParameters.Remove('Days')

# Splat the remaining arguments and filter out files newer than $Days 
Get-ChildItem @PSBoundParameters -File|Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -lt $Threshold} |%{ Remove-Item $_.FullName }
```

Comment: Wow this is great, exactly what I was after. I will post my updated script shortly

Comment: Mathias, could you please let me know what the `-File` parameter/switch is doing in this case? Is it detecting whether any of the parameters contains a path to a file?

Comment: It tells Get-ChildItem to only return files, not folders